# triggering jQuery show on focus not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, click, focus, show

I'm triggering showing a textarea when I focus on a checkbox that says 'other' , so the user only needs it when when they click that choice from amongst other checkboxes. (http://air.abricot-production.com/alliance-of-independent-restaurants/restaurant-membership-application.html).

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".BusTypeOtherTextArea").hide();
            $(".BusTypeOther").focus(function () {
                $(".BusTypeOtherTextArea").show("fast");
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

focus works fine on desktop but not on mobile? If I use click it works on both but doesn't leave the checkbox selected. How do I make this work for mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".BusTypeOtherTextArea").hide();
        $(".BusTypeOther").one('click focus', function() {
            $(".BusTypeOtherTextArea").show("fast");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a workaround for this, as i see it should be something like:

```
$('.checkBox').click(function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')) {
    // show textarea
  } else {
    // hide
  }
});
```

I suggest not using focus, especially where you dont have this gesture in mobile(tablet/phone) devices.

Comment: My testarea is no longer hidden to start with. Sorry can't seem to format as code with indents etc


     $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".BusTypeOtherTextArea").hide();
     $(".BusTypeOther").click(function () {
     if($(this).prop("checked")) {
     $(".BusTypeOtherTextArea").show("fast");
     } else {
     $(".BusTypeOtherTextArea").hide("fast");
     });
     });

Comment: Thanks Ben, the .one('click focus', function() seems a good solution.